# Laravel + Vue project--[vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk dashboard failed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I am working on a Laravel and Vue project, at the moment of executing the server
php run serve the project works normally, I can log in normally but, when I run the vue compilation command npm run watch or npm run dev the page stops loading and throws me an error in the console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGrav.png)

the composition of the webpack.mix.js file is this:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: '/mediamanager/public',
        publicPath: '/',
        chunkFilename: 'js/components/[name].js',
    }
});
```

Comment: delete node_modules folder and reinstall it with **npm install** then run npm run watch

Comment: Kindly comment in English.

Comment: I did it and it doesn't work, the problem is when I run the debug command it doesn't work anymore, it sends me that error